# How can I fix jetifier error in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

> Could not find androidx.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and tried many ways from adding repositories to build.gradle to removing proxy settings and ... but didn't work, finally I found the solution.
First close Android Studio, then go to "C:\Users<User Name>" and delete the ".gradle" directory.
Open Android Studio and sync your project.